# Spin image onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript

Like the title says, I am trying to rotate an image once a user clicks a button. I am new to javasript so I am still trying to figure out how things work. I have found a good example but the two images they have are always spinning. I want my image to just spin once for 45 degrees.

I want the image to spin like the ones here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Pvtzv/276/ but not everytime just once

Here is what I have so far:

```
   function doSpin()
{

    wheel = new Image();
    //wheel.onload = initialDraw; // Once the image is loaded from file this function is called to draw the image in its starting position.
    wheel.src = "./female_avatar.gif";
        var surfaceContext = surface.getContext('2d');
surfaceContext.drawImage(wheel, 0, 0);

p += .02;

var r = 100;
var xcenter = 150;
var ycenter = 150;


var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r* Math.cos(p)));
var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(p)));
var newLeft1 = Math.floor(xcenter + -(r* Math.cos(p)));
var newTop1 = Math.floor(ycenter + -(r * Math.sin(p)));

     wheel.animate({
        top: newTop,
        left: newLeft,
    }, 2, function() {
        doSpin()
            });

       }
```

In my html

```
    <button onclick="doSpin()">spin image</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `doSpin()` callback in the `animate()` function:

```
wheel.animate({
    top: newTop,
    left: newLeft,
}, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="moveit();">spin image</button>
```

and add the code in script tag

```
function moveit() {
    p += .02;

    var r = 100;
    var xcenter = 150;
    var ycenter = 150;


    var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r* Math.cos(p)));
    var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(p)));
    var newLeft1 = Math.floor(xcenter + -(r* Math.cos(p)));
    var newTop1 = Math.floor(ycenter + -(r * Math.sin(p)));

    $('#friends').animate({
            top: newTop,
            left: newLeft,
        }, 2, function() {
            moveit()
                });
    $('#friends2').animate({
        top: newTop1,
        left: newLeft1,
    },10, function() {
        moveit();
    });
 }
```

it worked here on **http://jsfiddle.net/cExsw/**